Create CustomResource containing K8s objects, using fabric8 Kubernetes Java client
I am trying to use fabric8 Java Kubernetes Client to create a CustomResource. I have already deployed a CRD into my cluster. This CRD has a ConfigMap in the spec. In my code, I am trying to create the CustomResource, but it's getting created without the ConfigMap.
CRD I've deployed in my cluster:
apiVersion: apiextensions.k8s.io/v1
kind: CustomResourceDefinition
metadata:
  name: namespaceoperatortests.namespace.com
spec:
  group: namespace.com
  conversion:
    strategy: None
  scope: Namespaced
  names:
    kind: NamespaceOperatorTest
    listKind: NamespaceOperatorTestList
    plural: namespaceoperatortests
    singular: namespaceoperatortest
  versions:
    - name: v1
      served: true
      storage: true
      schema:
        openAPIV3Schema:
          description: CronTab is the schema for crontab API 
          type: object
          properties:
            apiVersion:
              description: 'APIVersion defines the versioned schema of this representation
                of an object. Servers should convert recognized schemas to the latest
                internal value, and may reject unrecognized values. More info: https://git.k8s.io/community/contributors/devel/sig-architecture/api-conventions.md#resources'
              type: string
            kind:
              description: 'Kind is a string value representing the REST resource this
                object represents. Servers may infer this from the endpoint the client
                submits requests to. Cannot be updated. In CamelCase. More info: https://git.k8s.io/community/contributors/devel/sig-architecture/api-conventions.md#types-kinds'
              type: string  
            metadata:
              type: object
            spec:
              description: CronTabSpec defines desired state of cron tab 
              type: object
              properties:
                cronSpec:
                  type: string
                image:
                  type: string
                configMap:
                  properties:
                    data:
                      additionalProperties:
                        type: string
                      type: object
                    name:
                      type: string
                  required:
                  - data
                  - name
                  type: object
            status:
              description: CronTabStatus defines observed state of cron tab 
              type: object
              properties:
                conditions:
                  description: 'INSERT ADDITIONAL STATUS FIELD - define observed state
                  of cluster Important: Run "make" to regenerate code after modifying
                  this file'
                  items: 
                    properties:
                      message:
                        type: string
                      lastTransitionTime:
                        format: date-time
                        type: string
                    type: object
                  type: array
              type: object
          type: object
      subresources:
        status: {}

As you can see part of the spec is a ConfigMap object. I'm having trouble creating the CustomResource to have this ConfigMap spec. This is what I've tried that's gotten me the furthest, it creates the CustomResource but I don't see the ConfigMap.
NamespaceOperatorTest.java
@Version("v1")
@Group("namespace.com")
public class NamespaceOperatorTest
    extends CustomResource<NamespaceOperatorTestSpec, NamespaceOperatorTestStatus>
    implements Namespaced {}

NamespaceOperatorTestSpec.java
@JsonDeserialize(using = JsonDeserializer.None.class)
@Getter
@Setter
public class NamespaceOperatorTestSpec {

  private String cronSpec;
  private String image;
  private JSONObject ConfigMapSpec;
}

Code in my main class to create the CR:
NamespaceOperatorTest namespaceOperator = new NamespaceOperatorTest();
// Create spec
NamespaceOperatorTestSpec namespaceOperatorSpec = new NamespaceOperatorTestSpec();
namespaceOperatorSpec.setCronSpec("cronSpecString");
namespaceOperatorSpec.setImage("imageString");

// Create ConfigMap
JSONObject configMap = new JSONObject("{\"data\":{},\"name\":\"test-configmap\"}");
namespaceOperatorSpec.setConfigMapSpec(configMap);

namespaceOperator.setSpec(namespaceOperatorSpec);

// Add metadata
ObjectMeta meta = new ObjectMetaBuilder().withName("code-namespace-operator").build();
namespaceOperator.setMetadata(meta);

NamespaceOperatorTest createdNamespaceOperator =
        nsOpClient.inNamespace("default").resource(namespaceOperator).create();

The created CR is this, it's missing the ConfigMap:
apiVersion: namespace.com/v1
kind: NamespaceOperatorTest
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2024-06-13T05:15:18Z"
  generation: 1
  name: code-namespace-operator
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "152140251"
  uid: ab55bb3a-0155-4793-983a-d2387db270e6
spec:
  cronSpec: cronSpecString
  image: imageString

How can I create the Custom resource in my code correctly with the ConfigMap object?
